# How can I display a Save As dialog in an Electron App?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am writing a NodeJS Electron App to be distributed on all platforms. I have a download button that I would like to pop open a Save As dialog with the file being provided from the server. Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Here are the things I have tried that work when running the node app locally but fail after I have packaged the app with electron-packager:

- Setting window.location.href to the location of the file
- Setting the src of a hidden iframe to the location of the file

When running the packaged mac app, the "did-fail-load" event is fired and prevents the Save As dialog from showing. When looking at the network requests, I can see that the file is successfully retrieved from the server. I can't seem to figure out why the "did-fail-load" event is being fired.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at this page on the electron docs https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md

There is a section about **dialog.showSaveDialog**

Then you can use the URL from the save dialog with a function similar to the one below to save it to that location.

```
session.on('will-download', function(event, item, webContents) {
  event.preventDefault();
  require('request')(item.getUrl(), function(data) {
    require('fs').writeFileSync('/somewhere', data);
  });
});
```

Found on this page https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't able to get this method to work. I think I was having a problem with requiring libraries in the main process vs the renderer process. My original approach worked after I killed all my node modules and reinstalled them. Not sure exactly what was causing the issue, but works now!

Answer (score 10):

Below is an example if you want to use renderer only. On click Electron will show standard browser's Save As dialog. No need of `remote` nor `fs`.

```
<!--html-->
<button onclick="saveFile()">SAVE AS</button>
```

In the renderer javascript file:

```
// renderer javascript file
function saveFile() {
    const content = "File content to save";
    const element = document.createElement("a");
    const file = new Blob([content], {type: "text/plain"});
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "file.txt";
    element.click();
}
```

(I'm on mac and haven't tried it on a Windows machine)

Comment: If you don't want a dialog to be shown to the user, set the path by calling `item.setSavePath` in the `will-download` event - see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

On the HTML button:

```
<button onclick='myUrlSaveAs("http://www.example.com/path/to/file.jpg")'>Save As</button>
```

In your javascript file:

```
// Include in the render side
var elerem = require('electron').remote;
var dialog = elerem.dialog;
var app = elerem.app;

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


function myUrlSaveAs(remoteUrl){
    // app.getPath("desktop")       // User's Desktop folder
    // app.getPath("documents")     // User's "My Documents" folder
    // app.getPath("downloads")     // User's Downloads folder

    var toLocalPath = path.resolve(app.getPath("desktop"), path.basename(remoteUrl) 

    var userChosenPath = dialog.showSaveDialog({ defaultPath: toLocalPath });

    if(userChosenPath){
        download (remoteUrl, userChosenPath, myUrlSaveAsComplete)
    }


}

function myUrlSaveAsComplete(err){
    alert("done");
}


function download (url, dest, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close(cb); // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
        fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
        if (cb) cb(err.message);
    });
};
```

Comment: From all the posts I've tried this was the only one that worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question looking for the opposite effect - how to download a file in an Electron app *without* showing a save dialog. So maybe this is also helpful to others turning up here.

If you set a path in the [will-download](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#event-will-download) event handler, then Electron will skip displaying the dialog. For example (from https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/download-item)

```
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const win = new BrowserWindow()
win.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
  // Set the save path, making Electron not to prompt a save dialog.
  item.setSavePath('/tmp/save.pdf')
})
```