# Electron save as giving long server URL as title

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron save as dialog is giving me a long URL as title.

```
mainWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', function (event, item, webContents) {
    item.on('updated', () => {});
    item.on('done', (e, state) => {});
});
```

I seen this: [How can I display a Save As dialog in an Electron App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979630/).
But it's giving me "item object destroyed".
If it's a post call how to pass data to the request.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will solve your problem.

```
dialog.showSaveDialog({"title":"RssReader.pdf"},function(filename){
                    console.log(filename);
                    webview.printToPDF({},function(error,data){
                        if(error) alert(error);
                        else{
                            fs.writeFile(filename, data,function(error){
                                if (error) alert(error);
                                else
                                    alert('PDF saved successfully')
                            });
                        }
                    });
                })
```

Comment: My ajax call passing lots of data. How to pass that data to webview.printPDF.

Comment: DO you want it data pass data to webView or you want some data in webview to be printed

Comment: First download it in some temp location. Then open a save dialog and then move it to that location. I that approach ok?

Comment: Yes that approach is also good, and delete the tmp file after it had been saved to other location.